# Runtime weaving doesn't seem to work in WebLogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, weblogic, eclipselink

I'm trying to deploy a webapp which uses JPA 2.0 with the EclipseLink implementation to a WebLogic 10.3.6 server.

When I was developing the app, I used a Tomcat server to test it. As Tomcat is not an application server, I used Spring's load time weaver to do the weaving:

```
<bean id="emFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property value="classpath:META-INF/myPersistence.xml" name="persistenceXmlLocation" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Oracle's documentation says that "Dynamic byte code weaving is automatically enabled in Java EE 5-compliant application servers such as Oracle WebLogic", so I removed the `loadTimeWeaver` property from the entity manager factory bean:

```
<bean id="emFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property value="classpath:META-INF/myPersistence.xml" name="persistenceXmlLocation" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

But when I try to deploy my webapp to WebLogic, it throws the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer
>   without LoadTimeWeaver specified

Do I need to do something to enable the runtime weaving, even when Oracle's documentation says that it's enabled by default?

Maybe it's because WebLogic 10.3.6 implements the Java EE 5 specification instead of Java EE 6, and so, it doesn't support JPA 2.0 out of the box: I needed to install a patch and renaming my persistence.xml file to something else (in this case myPersistence.xml) so that WebLogic can't find it. If this is the case, how can I enable runtime weaving in the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I just needed to add this to applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:load-time-weaver />
```